# Use NIO with Image IO or Thumbnailator

Tags: thumbnails, nio, javax.imageio

I am planning to use [Thumbnailator](https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/)  to generate thumbnails for large size (0.5-10MB) images.
I looked through their code and found that [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) is being used to create thumbnails.

I am a newbie to both image files and their technicalities and the ImageIO package. What I would like to know is whether ImageIO uses (or can be made to use) NIO to read files and generate thumbnails? This will help in increasing performance in generating thumbnails, and we do have to generate a lot - 4 thumbnails per image, images ranging from 0.5 MB to 10 MB, at around 30 requests per second on an average.

Comment: What makes you think NIO will read a file faster than `java.io` streams? The time will be spent processing the image, not doing I/O.

Comment: @EJP, Isnt NIO faster than `io`? I would like to get that benefit as well when processing images, though I do agree that most of the CPU would be used in generating the thumbnail and not waiting for IO.

Comment: Have you made a proof of concept type implementation, to benchmark what kind of performance you can get, by using the library out of the box?

Comment: Yes, I did do that. For a set of images that I have, I am getting a best performance of around 9.2 images being thumbnailed into 4 different sizes per second.

Answer (score 0):

ImageIO uses an abstraction over streams, called `ImageInputStream`. Multiple implementations exists, backed by `InputStream`, `RandomAccessFile` etc.

To answer your question, **yes, it's possible to create plugins for ImageIO to provide `ImageInputStream`s backed by NIO** (`FileChannel` as an example). Have a look at the [ImageInputStreamSpi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ImageInputStreamSpi.html) class.

But I'm not sure if this will create much of an improvement compared to the existing implementation based on `RandomAccessFile` (many existing classes were retrofitted to benefit from NIO when it was introduced).

One thing that could potentially increase performance a lot, is calling `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`, to turn off disk caching (at the expense of in-memory caching).

Unfortunately, I don't know Thumbnailator, so I can't say how these options would affect the performance in your case.

Comment: I will try this out, and post results, probably next week, as the focus shifts from extracting performance, to delivering the sprint tasks.

Comment: I'm curious, did you make any progress with this?